# vs2015 coco2d-x 3.8 error reading characters of string

Tags: c++, c++11, cocos2d-x

please see below code: I don't know why this is happenning

```
bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
// initialize director
    auto director = Director::getInstance();
    auto glview = director->getOpenGLView();
    if (!glview) { 
        **glview = GLViewImpl::createWithRect("NewCocosProject", Rect(0, 0, 960, 640));**
        director->setOpenGLView(glview);
    }
}

bool GLViewImpl::initWithRect(const std::string& viewName, Rect rect, float frameZoomFactor)
{
    setViewName(viewName);
}
```

[image: below is screenshot]

if I continue, I'll get this error:
[image]

could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after 2 weeks struggle, I realized that, I created the coco project with PREBUILD library, then after I change source project it won't affect the library, so I get various funny errors, I download the latest coco studio again, when I create new project, it shows the option: prebuilt or source code, so I create with source code projects, then I can run it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please create a separate string object before passing:

```
const & tmpString = std::string("NewCocosProject");
glview = GLViewImpl::createWithRect(tmpString, Rect(0, 0, 960, 640));
                                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

I admit, I am guessing here, but might work for you.